# filename encoding on server

Tags: php, .htaccess, encoding, filenames

another encoding question.

On my server, I want to have the possibility of having mp3-files with utf-encoded filenames, for exampe Начало.mp3 .

Now when I save (or rename via my FTP client) a file to Начало.mp3, after refreshing, this file will automatically be renamed to ??????.mp3.

I added a htaccess to both the parent and the directory itself, with an AddDefaultCharSet utf-8 , but the problem stays the same.

Any ideas?

Greetz and thanks

Maenny

Comment: I guess this is a question for serverfault.com. It deals with server filesystem encodings, you also need to provide what is your server and how are you actually doing things. If you use an FTP client and have the same problem, then it's nothing .htaccess can solve.

Answer (score 0):

I am in agreement with Vinko, might be a hosting issue, but you can also check your FTP client utf8 mode... If nothing else you can delete, rename locally and upload the file again.